# Whats the correct way to update a Master-Detail with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, master-detail

I'm working with *offline* Master-Detail like this:

[image]

Currently I'm deleting collections and then adding them again. even though not all the items of the collection have been modified

*Is that the proper way to do an update?*

**Edit:**

Added Code and some modificatins based on comments:

```
  CreateMasterFromView(){
       Master aMaster = new Master();
       aMaster.MasterId = View.Id  // I set Id because I'm editing this master
       aMaster.MasterValue = "Some value";

       foreach (var detail in View.Details)
       {
         Detail aDetail = new Detail();
         aDetail.DetailValue = View.DetailValue;
         aDetail.MasterId = View.Id // 
         aMaster.Details.add(aDetail);
       }    
        Save(aMaster);
    }

Save (Master aMaster){
    if (aMaster.MasterId != 0)
    {                  
        var oldDetails = Dba.Details.Where(detail=> detail.MasterId == aMaster.Id);
        foreach (var oldDetail  in oldDetails )
                    {
                       Dba.Details.Remove(oldDetail);
                    }
        foreach (var detail in aMaster.Details)
                    {
                        Dba.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Added;
                    }
    }
    Dba.Entry(aMaster).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Dba.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What are you supposed to achieve? Insert new Master? Update scalar Master property? Delete all Master relation? All of it?

Comment: @Szer I''ll edit the question, im trying to update my master with new Details and new properties values.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You mention updating details but your code *deletes* details. If you want to delete a master's details just call `Remove` on *them*, don't reload them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry that code was confused. I'm trying to update the master entity with (new, modified and maybe deleted) details.

Comment: Are you trying to save changes on your PK value ?

Comment: @xum59 Yes im setting my Pk Value MasterId with the existing in Db

Comment: I don't think EF will like changing the PK of an entity. Anyway, you shall remove (or eventually update) Details _before_ changing the Master PK or their DB counterparts will refer to a non-existing MasterId

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but this should work :

```
Master.Details.Clear();
Dba.SaveChanges();
```

EF does a lot of tracking to its entities, don't try to work with EF as you'd work with SQL.

Comment: afaik that wont work if `Master` is in non-attached state and thus non-tracked

Comment: @Szer why do you assume `Master` isn't attached? The only case where that could happen is if you are inserting a new Master. In which case, you won't need to delete anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if it comes outside of Domain or comes as DTO mapped to non-DTO or... Tons of cases

Answer (score 1):

These examples below are useful when your entities come in non-Attached state (outside of Domain in multi-tier app its common scenario):

```
public class Master
{
    public long MasterId { get; set; }
    public object MasterValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public long DetailId { get; set; }
    public long MasterId { get; set; }
    public object DetailValue { get; set; }
    public Master Master { get; set; }
}

public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Master> Master { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Detail> Detail { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public void ChangeMasterValue(Master master, object newValue)
    {
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            context.Master.Attach(master);
            master.MasterValue = newValue;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteAllDetailsFromMaster(Master master)
    {
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            context.Master.Attach(master);
            master.Details.Clear();
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void AddDetailToMaster(Master master, Detail newDetail)
    {
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            context.Master.Attach(master);
            master.Details.Add(newDetail);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteDetailFromMaster(Master master, Detail detailToDelete)
    {
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            context.Master.Attach(master);
            master.Details.Remove(detailToDelete);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateMaster(Master master)
    {
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            context.Master.Attach(master);
            context.Entry(master).State=EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the multiple calls to `SaveChanges`? A single call at the end is enough. This code will result in inconsistent data if anything interrupts the code. A single SaveChanges on the other will run inside a single transaction, ensuring all changes are consistent. Wrapping this in a transaction will simply cover up the unnecessary saves

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thats kinda different cases in one method. They are supposed to be in different methods.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many methods there are, if you call SaveChanges multiple times, you'll hurt performance *and* possibly corrupt data. If you use multiple methods that open/save/close context, you run the exact same risk

Comment: thanks! in my case, the test method, gets the object already modified by parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos just for you, I rewrite it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and about DbContext usage. Its offtopic, but it should we created and disposed per request/command. Thats how UnitOfWork pattern works usually. And you will get appropriate data from Database. With latest EF versions best practice for context managment is to shorten lifetime.

Comment: your `DeleteDetailFromMaster` is exactly like `AddDetailToMaster` method? it should be `Remove` (instead of `Add`) in the `DeleteDetailFromMaster`. BTW this scenario is useful if the input data is detached (it should also be noted clearly at first).

Comment: @Hopeless thanks, edited. And also added disclaimer at top

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to update an entity:

1. get old entity from db then update properties which are changed and
   call save changes.
2. directly attach your new entity to db and call save changes. (no need to get old entity from db)

In your case it can be like this:

```
if (Master.MasterId != 0)
{
     var oldDetails = Dba.Detail.Where(det => det.MasterId == Master.MasterId);
     foreach (var olddetail in oldDetails)
     {
           // don't call remove here just update new values in those properties which are changed like this   
     }
     //no need to set modified state because this olddetail is in current request
}
Dba.SaveChanges();}
```

Or second way:

```
if (Master.MasterId != 0)
{
    Dba.Entry(Master).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
Dba.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The second one give me the exception that I wrote in my post, the first case is not saving anything.

Comment: this exception shows that your Master entity have some navigation properties with non nullable foreign keys but in your data fk values are null... so please check the data and if you don't want to update navigation properties then set navigation properties to null before modifying

Comment: if it does not work please update your Master entity and other entities which have fk relationships with this in your question for better understanding.